# What are good ways to present proofs of theorems requiring auxiliary lemmas?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-writing

I am writing an academic paper for submission to a journal. One of my co-authors wrote the following:

> **Theorem** Statement of the theorem
>
> **Proof of theorem** We first show the following result
>
> **Lemma** Statement of lemma used to prove the theorem

However, I think that it is more natural to present things in the following way:

> **Theorem** Statement of the theorem
>
> We first show the following result which is used to prove the theorem:
>
> **Lemma** Statement of lemma used to prove the theorem
>
> **Proof of theorem** blah blah

I understand that this is a subjective question so I am happy to mark this as community wiki if most people feel that it belongs there.

Comment: I more often see the order lemma, theorem, proof.

Comment: Theorem--->lemma--->Proof-of-lemma---->proof of theorem.

Comment: I agree that the second way is better. The first way leaves the question unanswered whether the lemma is only formulated in the context of the theorem, in the context of its proof (which may be more restrictive, e. g., due to WLOG assumptions or cases) or in the context of the surrounding paper. In the second way, it is clear that the context is that of the surrounding paper.

Comment: Obviously which is more natural / easier to read depends a lot on the specific context (for example, the relative length of the proof of the theorem and/or lemma, and whether the lemma is really just a "claim" on the way to proving the theorem or rather more independent).

Comment: +1 for asking such a question, although I understand the close voters: such a question might be better at math.stackexchange.

Comment: I think this question is too localized for MO as phrased currently, but that doesn't make MSE a better fit. A better way to phrase it might be, "What are good ways to present proofs of theorems requiring auxiliary lemmas?" Certainly, though, this question is of interest to research mathematicians, and is specifically about mathematical writing.

Comment: The first way has a more educational flavor that is going better with the flow of thinking. It is like saying that "now, it is enough to show that..."; and that is your lemma.

Comment: Dear Coder, I prefer to adopt the second style, rather than having nested proofs, for reasons similar to darij's: the hypotheses in force at any point become clearer, and also the logical flow is easier for the reader.  Regards,

Comment: It can be helpful to the reader (or at least to me) to have the statement of the theorem appear before technical lemmas that are used in the proof. It's irritating to have to flip through some pages of before seeing the statement they're used to prove. So I would go for the second method, in general.

Comment: For what it's worth, here is my perspective of a graduate student: if there is nothing wrong with lemma -> proof of lemma -> theorem -> proof of theorem, then there is no need to make things more complicated for the reader than they already are, by nesting stuff. Unless it is an overview of a result, a proof should follow the statement immediately.The reader can always skip lemma/corollary/proof on his own if he wishes to do so, so there is hardly any need to break logical flow. Everything else is just friggin' annoying to read and understand!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The guiding principle should be: think of your readers.  Nesting results inside the proofs of other results can make things confusing.  I am looking right now at a paper that has three instances of that, and one of them is truly egregious: the bracket diagram is like this: $((((()))(())))$.

Maybe one nested lemma is ok, but if I could avoid it I would just put the lemma before, and say something like: "The following lemma will be used in the proof of Theorem 1."  If you really want to state the theorem before the lemma, then your second option is better.

OK, I'll stop grinding this axe now.

Comment: In the introduction/statement of the main results, one can always state the most important theorems in any order one sees fit. So, there is hardly a single reason why to break the logical flow of things later when all the lemmas and theorems are presented rigorously with their proofs. If anything, it makes following the rigor only more difficult. Putting lemmas and their proofs inside other proofs is just bad style.